# How to specify method return type list length in Python?

Tags: python, return-type

Let's say i have a method like this:

```
def return_list_with_length_2(self) -> list[int]:
    return [0, 1]
```

is there a way to specify that the length of the returned list is always 2?

Comment: Is using a tuple instead of a list an option?

Comment: @KonradRudolph i guess it would be, is it possible to specify the length there?

Comment: A 2-element list is a different type than a list that can have an arbitrary length. Python's type-hinting does not, at this time, support this kind of dependent type.

Comment: @coding_noob Not only is it possible, it's the usual use-case! — see the posted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tuple as output:

```
def return_tuple_with_length_2(self) -> tuple[int, int]:
    return (0, 1)
```